# Can properties that are not persisted have getters and setters?

Tags: ios, core-data, persistence, getter-setter

I am using getters and setters on some computed properties, and I do not want to store the values for these properties in the database. Can properties that are not persisted have getters and setters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course non-persisted properties can have getters and setters. There is no relationship between the 2 things, other than the fact that custom getters/setters are a pretty common place to put your code for reading/writing to your persistent store.

Comment: Does a non-persistent property need to be added to the core data model as a transient attribute in order for the getter/setter to work properly? And if not, in what case would one need to add the transient attribute to the model?

Comment: No. As I said before getters and setters and persistent data storage are completely unrelated.